# Model with nested Map to set on Firebase (json_annotation.dart)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

My Firebase Database model looks like:

```
dbRef
    |___userId
             |____Cars
                  |____Alfa_Romeo
                  |             |____Year: 1992
                  |             |____Price: 10000
                  |__________Audi
                  |             |____Year: 1998
                  |             |____Price: 3000
                  |___________BMW
                                |____Year: 2001
                                |____Price: 7000
```

Then I have a Class Car that looks like

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';


part 'car.g.dart';

/// An annotation for the code generator to know that this class needs the
/// JSON serialization logic to be generated.
@JsonSerializable()

class Car {
  Carta(this.model, this.details);

  String model;
  List details;

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CarFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CarToJson(this);
}
```

Now when I set the data to Firebase I get this:

```
dbRef
    |___userId
              |____Cars
                      |____Alfa_Romeo
                      |____Year: 1992
                      |____Price: 10000
```

... and I want it to be like the model from the first diagram. 
How can I nest the details in the "Model" child?
Can anyone help me with this, please?

EDIT: Just to be sure I'm clear what I want.
This code is from the  Flutter Team [docs example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#generating-code-for-nested-classes):

```
import 'address.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class User {
  String firstName;
  Address address;

  User(this.firstName, this.address);

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

This code generates the following output:

```
name: John, address: {street: My st., city: New York}}
```

And what I want to achieve is John to became a Child key and the Adress to be nested inside, because there could be more than one Adress Array. The Adress field should become a Key (it will be unique) and then it will have a map of items and each item have only 2 fields description and price.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest breaking the details out into their own class like this example, https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#generating-code-for-nested-classes.

*Edit*

Rather than using JsonSerializable, try mapping the model manually and copying the remaining properties to another Map.

```
class Car {
  Car({this.model, this.details});

  String model;
  Map<String, dynamic> details;

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    Map<String, dynamic> details = Map<String, dynamic>.from(json);
    details.remove('model');

    return new Car(
      model: json['model'],
      details: details
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = Map<String, dynamic>.from(details);
    json['model'] = model;

    return json;
  }
}
```

Comment: Part of my code came from there, however I'm struggle with this part because I have no idea what the keys will be. It may be cars, it may be model name, it may be truck. Same with the details. They may be price, may be km. may be whatever the user input and the only cetain thing is that will be a map of the type {String : String}. Hence I need more abastract model that leaves mi to put a map inside of the key "model". I don't know if I explained it well.

Comment: In that case, try changing the details type to `Map<string, dynamic>`. If that still does not work, try creating the `ModelDetails` class that just has a details property.

Comment: It doesn't create the output I want. I'll edit my question with the example from the flutter team code and explain why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Thanks, but this one still doesn't return the details nested in the model. I found a workarround that will post when I have more time. Untill then I'm open to test other solutions. It's important to return all the details nested in the model, because there's another class User that gets nested class Car and then I post the User to Firebase.